# Android: have ListView only show selected item?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to find if there is a way to have a ListView only show the single selected item (or Activated item for my case).  What I would like to have is a ListView (not an ExpandableListView) that shows a list of choices.  Upon clicking on one of the items, the item would become selected/activated, and the view would collapse to only show that single highlighted row.  Clicking again on the item would deselect/deactivate and would result in the list expanding to again show all the choices.

```
/* Setup the ListView */
    List mItems = getItems(someCriteria);

    ListView lview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
    ArrayAdapter<SomeItem> anAdaptor =
            new ArrayAdapter<SomeItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, mItems);

    lview.setAdapter(anAdaptor);
    /* Handles the item selection using Activated property */
    lview.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector);
    lview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

And I have a list_selector resource (\res\drawable\list_selector.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />

<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />

<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" /> <!--  @drawable/tab_focus -->

<!-- Pressed -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /> <!--  @drawable/tab_press -->

</selector>
```

And the pressed or selected resources look like (\res\drawable\pressed.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/DarkGray"/>
</shape>
```

And my setOnItemClickListener for the ListView:

```
     lview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {

            ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_listview);

            SomeItem an_item = (SomeItem) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

            lview.setSelection(position);
            lview.setItemChecked(position, true);
            lview.invalidateViews();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache in a separate variable the selected "SomeItem".

Then both in the getCount() and the getItem(...) of the adapter, you check wether that variable is null or not, and just show that item (or the normal items if is null)

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
   if(selectedItem != null)
   {
       return 1;
   }

   return super.getCount(); 
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
   if(selectedItem != null)
   {
       return selectedItem ;
   }

   return super.getItem(position); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to change your adapter with the new data to be included (removing programmatically those items not needed).

Once you do that you need to to draw again the complete list (adding the new adapter to your list).

Probably you have included an "onClick" answer in your listview to react to this event, I would recommend you to create a method in your activity to perform the new adapter adding and inside the onClick method (using host) a call to that method.